# ruby multiple string match with

Tags: ruby

i've written a few lines of code like this :

```
if( (user_input.include?('string_a') || 
    (user_input.include? ('string_b')) || 
    (user_input.include?('string_c')) ) 
    && 
    user_input.include?('string_d_keyword'))
    ....
end # if
```

is there any function which can simplify the "multiple or string match" by taking multiple arguments and look like this ?

```
if( (user_input.multi_include_or?('string_a','string_b','string_c')) 
    && (user_input.include?('string_d_keyword')))
.....
end # if
```

i hope to do these all in a single line and so i've leave out the option of "case when".

Thanks~

Comment: I deleted my answer after seeing that I misread the question. I thought `user_input` was an array of strings. It's perfectly clear that it's a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a regex match using `|` (or):

```
if user_input.match? /string_a|string_b|string_c|string_d_keyword/
  …
end
```

If your strings are in an array you can use `Regexp.union` to convert them to the corresponding regex:

```
if user_input.match? Regexp.union(strings)
  …
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  BTW, i have to use this format to make it work :
user_input.match( /string_a|string_b/ )
thx again~

Comment: `Regex.union` should be `Regexp.union` fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array and [any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
> user_input = "string_a"
=> "string_a"
> ["asd","string_a"].any? {|a| user_input.include? a}
=> true
```

Comment: What's with the downvote? Is there something wrong with this solution?